# Is it necessary to use wp_reset_query() in a WP_Query call?

Tags: wp-query

I'm using the following code to retrieve posts:

```
<?php
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=5&cat=3');

while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <div class="meta">
        By <?php the_author() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="storycontent">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Do I need to use `wp_reset_query()`? If I do, where should I place it?

Comment: Related: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: If you're relying on the main query object somewhere else in the page, then Yes! you should call it, to ensure the main query object contains the data is did before you iterated over your custom query. When you call `the_post()` method(ie. `$my_custom_query->the_post()`) you refill the post variables the main query looks at, the reset refills these vars with the previous data when you call it. It is good practice to use resets after custom queries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi **@janoChen:**

Simple answer: *no.*

What follows is what the PHP code for the function `wp_reset_query()` from `/wp-includes/query.php` in WordPRess v3.0.4 as well as the functions subsequently called. You can see that it's primarily about in modifying global variables.

When you use `new WP_Query($args)` you will be assigning the return value from values to a local variable so, unless you are doing something so complex that you'd already know the answer to this question for then no, you don't need to call `wp_reset_query()`:

```
function wp_reset_query() {
  unset($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
  $GLOBALS['wp_query'] =& $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
  wp_reset_postdata();
}

function wp_reset_postdata() {
  global $wp_query;
  if ( !empty($wp_query->post) ) {
    $GLOBALS['post'] = $wp_query->post;
    setup_postdata($wp_query->post);
  }
}

function setup_postdata($post) {
  global $id, $authordata, $day, $currentmonth, $page, $pages, $multipage, $more, $numpages;

  $id = (int) $post->ID;

  $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);

  $day = mysql2date('d.m.y', $post->post_date, false);
  $currentmonth = mysql2date('m', $post->post_date, false);
  $numpages = 1;
  $page = get_query_var('page');
  if ( !$page )
    $page = 1;
  if ( is_single() || is_page() || is_feed() )
    $more = 1;
  $content = $post->post_content;
  if ( strpos( $content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) ) {
    if ( $page > 1 )
      $more = 1;
    $multipage = 1;
    $content = str_replace("\n<!--nextpage-->\n", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
    $content = str_replace("\n<!--nextpage-->", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
    $content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->\n", '<!--nextpage-->', $content);
    $pages = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $content);
    $numpages = count($pages);
  } else {
    $pages = array( $post->post_content );
    $multipage = 0;
  }

  do_action_ref_array('the_post', array(&$post));

  return true;
}
```

-Mike

Comment: @janoChen - heh. He's definitely been pushing me lately, that's for sure! I guess as they say, competition improves the breed *(but sure keeps me from getting anything else productive done! '-)*

Comment: Just for others reading this, since this is still the accepted answer (@Rarst's answer should be accepted). Since the OP uses `the_post()` in his code, best practices dictate that he must use `wp_reset_postdata()`. `wp_reset_query()` calls `wp_reset_postdata()`, so that will work, though the other thing `wp_reset_query()` does - resetting the `$wp_query` global variable - is not necessary, but not harmful in this case. So the answer is actually __YES__

Answer (score 22):

It is not necessary for `WP_Query` by itself, **but** it is necessary (or at least good thing to do) if you use any related functions/methods ( such as `the_post()` or `setup_postdata()` ) to fill global variables with your data.

Basically creating new `WP_Query` object is merely data retrieval, but using it to run active loop and making data accessible to template tags does modify environment and it is good to reset everything afterwards.

Overall - it isn't meaningful performance penalty to call it, so it is easier to always call it than deciding if you should or forgetting about it and having something mysteriously broken.

**Update**

[`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L112) function seems to be more fitting choice. `wp_reset_query()` resets global `$wp_query` (which custom `WP_Query` object doesn't affect) **and** `$post` (which it might as above) variables. `wp_reset_postdata()` only restores `$post`, which should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you instantiate your own WP_Query object, its yours to do with what you will. However, if you tamper with the `global $wp_query` variable, well, then your in the global namespace affecting anyone's script who is concurrently using that variable. And if you do something to change the data in it, you must also reset it after your done using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom query like this

```
$cat = new WP_query(); 
$cat->query("cat=19,20,-23&showposts=5&orderby=rand"); 
while ($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); 
  $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true );
$img_arrays []= $data['productimage']; 
$lnk_arrays[] =get_permalink($post_ID); 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Then you won't run into problems. Otherwise, if on the same page there is another loop you are bound to get some unexpected results. I didn't used wp_reset_query() in the above code (which was placed in my header.php file. Then when i got into single.php mostly i get the detail pages of other categories which was frustrating. Later, i realized that i forgot to reset the query at the top. Soon, it started working like a charm.