# How do I Use Multiple Loops with WP_Query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop, custom-post-type-archives

Hi I am trying to add post from a certain taxonomy term to a cpt loop. The code below is the code I am using.

```
    <?php // Create empty array to store post ids in
 $excludes = array();

                 $args=array(
                 'post_type' => array ('gallery','videos'),
     'taxonomy'=>'series',
     'term' => 'pretty-little-liars',
                 'post_status' => 'publish',
                );
               $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

But the problem with the code is that all of my post are now missing. I then learned that I needed to add a second loop. Ok so after reading up on [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage)

I tried to add a second loop but it gave me an error, and here is the code i used for that

```
        <?php // Create empty array to store post ids in
 $excludes = array();

                 $args=array(
                 'post_type' => array ('gallery','videos'),
     'taxonomy'=>'series',
     'term' => 'pretty-little-liars',
                 'post_status' => 'publish',
                );
               $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

// Restore original Query & Post Data
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

/* The 2nd Query (without global var) */
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The 2nd Loop
if ($query2->have_posts()) : while($query2->have_posts()) : $query2->the_post();

// Restore original Query & Post Data
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

It gave me this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /hermes/bosweb/web188/b1885/ipg.celebloidcom1/tvcafe/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/archive-pretty-little-liars.php on line 258

What am I doing wrong here, can anyone help me fix this. I am not going for a seperated structure in my loop but more of a together structure.

For Example I don't want the first loop at the top and the second loop at the bottom. I want them combined in one loop.

If you need more info or would like to see my whole php please let me know.

Comment: Your `if():` has to be closed, the `while():` too. See [syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: @toscho it says i have to add `endif;` do I add that after each `wp_reset_postdata();` ....if so i tried that but it didn't work. If i have to add `<?php endif; ?>` if so that I'm not sure it will work because i have php count codes in my loop as well, were can i upload the whole php file for you to see.

Answer (score 2):

As Toscho mentionned [above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78179/how-do-i-use-multiple-loops-with-wp-query#comment106673_78179), you didn't close your `if` and `while`. When in doubt, indent your codes to avoid confusion.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
  while($my_query->have_posts()) :
    $my_query->the_post();
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

/* The 2nd Query (without global var) */
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The 2nd Loop
if ($query2->have_posts()) :
  while($query2->have_posts()) :
    $query2->the_post();
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also, you don't need to use [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) with WP_Query. [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8031/is-it-necessary-to-use-wp-reset-query-in-a-wp-query-call) deals with that issue.

Comment: Hi thank you, but now it's only showing one post

Comment: You should set up your query parameters properly. Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: here is the archive file --> https://gist.github.com/4450181

Comment: You didn't declare `$args2` in the second `WP_Query`. You could do a `print_r($my_query)` and `print_r($query2)` to see the parameters, results and SQL used in the query. You didn't display anything in the loop either. `$my_query->the_post();` will not display your post content. Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: do you mean `$args2`=array .... how exactly do i declare `$args2` i do have this line for the second loop `$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );`

Comment: Yes `$args2 = array(...)` just like you did for `$args = array(...)`. You just need to fill required parameters in the array. Read the link above on `WP_Query`.

Comment: but i don't know what to put for the request, I just want that part to be the normal loop.

Comment: You should decide what posts you want first.

Comment: i don't want them in a certain order. I want them blended. If i post in my post type "Preetty Little Liars" I want it to show on the page. If i post in gallery and enter the term "Pretty Little Liars" in the taxonomy "Series" it should also show on that page as the latest post. Just like the normal loop. The latest post first.

Comment: i don't want them in a that kind of order. I want them to blend in with the post in my cpt archive. I have a CPT named "Pretty Little Liars" and the archive is in order from the last article posted. By adding post from my CPT's "Gallery" and "Videos" with the term "Pretty Little Liars" it should also show in the "Pretty Little Liars" CPT loop before the last post posted in the "Pretty Little Liars" CPT and If I post in the "Pretty Little Liars" CPT then the latest post should be on top again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6969/discussion-between-mihad-aiko-and-rrikesh)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your file you never declare $args2, also your page is really not written correctly. You are only getting one post because you are not in the loop properly, it is assuming it is inside a loop but it isn't.

Comment: I am new to this, I know somethings but this is my first time trying to mess with the loop, but can you tell me or show me exactly how to loop it properly. This is for a custom post type archive, each custom post type archive has a different style sheet as well.

Comment: I think you need a bit more fundamentals with the loop.
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/a-beginners-guide-to-the-wordpress-loop/