# Showing posts for today and future

Tags: posts, post-status

I'm using the following code to display posts with todays date or in the future... except the future part isn't working. If I take out the if statement then it shows all posts - in the past, present and future.

```
$today = date( 'd M' ); 
$pages = get_children( array(
    'post_status' => 'future,publish',
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'sort_order' => 'DESC'
) );
foreach ( $pages as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $item = get_the_date(); 
    if ($item >= $today) { 
        ?><h3><?php echo the_title(); ?> - <?php the_date(); ?></h3><?php
    }
}
wp_reset_query();
```

How can I display posts with todays date and posts in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_posts function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with [WP_Query params](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of get_children. The code will than look like this:

```
$today = getdate(); 
$pages = get_posts( array(
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ),
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'year' => $today["year"],
    'monthnum' => $today["mon"],
    'day' => $today["mday"]
) );
foreach ( $pages as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
        ?><h3><?php echo the_title(); ?> - <?php the_date(); ?></h3><?php
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Correct, the `post_status` can accept an array (or string) as its value.

Comment: Thanks, and also notice change in wp_reset_query - it transformed into wp_reset_postdata... Read more on wp_reset_query vs. wp_reset_postdata - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8031/is-it-necessary-to-use-wp-reset-query-in-a-wp-query-call

Answer (score 0):

Hook `posts_where` filter and add your condition to the sql query:

```
function wpse8170_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= sprintf( " AND post_date >= ''", date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
    return $where;
}

// add your hook
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse8170_filter_where' );

// get pages
$pages = get_children( array(
    'post_status' => 'future,publish',
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'sort_order' => 'DESC'
) );

// remove your hook to not have influence on other get posts queries
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse8170_filter_where' );

foreach ( $pages as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    ?><h3><?php echo the_title(); ?> - <?php the_date(); ?></h3><?php
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what it was doing...

It was measuring the day of the month against each other so I reversed it to `Ymd`.

Comment: Could you please add your code. Explaining code in plain words often leads to the wrong results. THanks.