# Multiple Loops Breaking Pages

Tags: posts, loop, pages

I'm new to WordPress, and I'm having an issue with "The Loop." I have a sidebar on the left side of a page that's supposed to show recent posts from two categories. In the middle of the page, there should be content for that specific page. In the right column, there should be posts for a specific category.

Here's the problem: When I set up the left column, the middle column shows the posts content instead of the pages. See http://opachicago.com/wp/ if that doesn't make sense.

Here's my Loop codes:

Left Column (which should show Latest Posts):

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=News and Events, Uncategorized&showposts=5'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>   
        <p><?php the_time('M j') ?>: <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Middle Column (which should show Page content):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page is behaving weirdly because you are using `query_posts` which clobbers the main query. Anything else on the page that depends on the main query has the wrong information after your `query_posts` runs. ***Don't use `query_posts`.***

```
$qry = new WP_Query('category_name=News and Events, Uncategorized&showposts=5'); 
if ($qry->have_posts()) { 
  while ($qry->have_posts()) {
   $qry->the_post(); 
   // your Loop as normal
  }
} else {
  // no posts found
}
```

At the end of this Loop the  `global $post` variable will be set to the last item in the secondary Loop, and not to the current item in the main query Loop. You can demonstrate this with the following code:

```
var_dump($post->post_name); // main Loop
$qry = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page','posts_per_page' => 1));
while ($qry->have_posts()) {
  $qry->the_post();
  var_dump($post->post_name); // secondary Loop
}
var_dump($post->post_name); // Still the secondary Loop
```

Since most Loops have `the_post()` at the beginning, that variable should be reset at that point, so resetting `$post` may not be necessary at all. To avoid that issue, I originally had `wp_reset_query` on the line following the end of the Loop, which does sort out `$post`, but as [@Rarst points out here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8048/21376), that is overkill and [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) would be the better choice.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: the codex is actually incorrect in the case of `wp_reset_query()`, you only need to use it if you've touched the `$wp_query` global. In this case `wp_reset_postdata()` is all you need (which `wp_reset_query()` itself calls after copying the `wp_the_query` global to `wp_query`).

Comment: @Milo : see the edit